# Clear the JavaScript console without a line being added

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-console

I want to clear the console, using `console.clear()`, but I don't want the line, `Console was cleared`, to printed out after the console was cleared. I didn't know how to go about doing this, and I found nothing on Google. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Probably not. Why do you  want that line to not be displayed?

Comment: It's not possible, you could print a bunch of `\n\n` or use CTRL+L (Chrome - Windows)